# Json dll not working

Tags: .net

hey guys, i was using Json dll in my project from quite sometime now but recently bymistakely i deleted those dll's now when i downloaded the dll from internet and added the reference to the assembly using Add-Reference, and run my application, it throws me this Error

`Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.`

i am totally got stuck here,, i dont understand why i am getting this error and how to resolve the same...

Please anyone knows how to resolve this issue please revert back soon, as this is very urgent..

Thanks and Regards
Abbas Electricwala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

There's your answer. Your compiler or runtime is older than the one used to build the DLL. Try upgrading your environment to to a newer version and see if that helps.

Alternatively, see if you can find an older version of the dll that matches your environment.

Comment: no worries. I just thought it was better to add to your answer than to write my own (since I was more or less going to write the same).

Comment: thanks a lot @Blender and @Klaus Byskov Hoffmann.
i downloaded the older version of the JSon dll and it worked...

Thanks a lot..

Comment: Hi guys now my issue is previously i was using the class JSonReader from Json dll and now i also implemented JsonCovert class for serializing ArrayList, now when i run site, it says JsonConvert does not exists, coz jsonConvert is in dll 2.0 and i am referncing 1.0, but when i also add 2.0 dll it throws an error saying jsonReader is exists in both Dll, how should i resolve this issue, as i cannot specify the namespace individually while using those class as there namespace are same. Please help me for how should i resolve this.

Comment: Ask that in a separate question. I can't code C#, so somebody else should help ;)